# Limiter per Page is not Working

Tags: magento-1, product-list, pagination, pager

On Product List page I added a filter Sort By:

- Newest Products
- Popularity
- Name From A-Z
- Name From Z-A
- Price - Low to High
- Price - High to Low

everything is functioning properly

but comes the problem when filter Results per Page (Show / limit how many products per page). I set 12, 24, 36, All.

Before I add Sort by Newest Products, all functioning normally include Show / product limit per page.
Related to Sort by Newest Products, I added this new/custom code below `<? Php echo $ this-> getToolbarHtml ()?>` to the list of products in the Grid view:

```
<?php
    if($currentCategoryId){
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortOrder();
        $direction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
        $display = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
        $limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();

         if($order == 'name') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }                
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)                                          
                 ->setOrder('name', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($limit);

            //echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
            //$_productCollection->printLogQuery(true);
         }

         if($order == 'price') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('price', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($limit);
         }

         if($order == 'position') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('position', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($limit);
         }

         if($order == '') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')
                 ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($limit);
        }
    }

?>
```

The full code (`andi\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`) can be found at Pastebin : *http://pastebin.com/U5UpgUmj*

Page Limit does not function.
When I click on page 1, it will look like in figure 1.
By the time I click on page 2, it will look like Figure 2 (image Page 2 - Error), where the picture repeats a number of 12. It should be on page 2 (image Page 2 - Should), which appear only 7 product images in page 2 ( from total of 19 products).

[image: Limit Product per Page]

I had read this tutorial : https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/limiting-collection-size-in-magento and try to use it.

How to limit per-page to function properly? Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@minesh-patel, after trying several times I finally get a code like this:

(without override / rewrite)

//Category and Limit Page

```
<?php
```

> $cat = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('cat');

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

> if($cat == '')

```
$currentCategoryId = $_category->getId();
```

> else
>
> $currentCategoryId = $cat;
>
> $limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
>               if($limit == ""){
>           $limit = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
>       }

```
?>
<!-- No Product -->
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml();
```

> $current_page = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();

```
?>
```

//layered navigation handling by attribute

```
$price = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $class = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('class');
        $silos = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('silos');

        if($price != ''){
            $arr_price = explode('-',$price);

            if($arr_price[1] == '')
                $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=> $arr_price[0]));
            else
                $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=> $arr_price[0], 'to' => $arr_price[1]));
        }

        if($class != ''){
            //$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('class');
            $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('class', $class);
        }

        if($silos != ''){
            $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('silos', $silos);
        }
    }

    if($limit != 'all'){
        $_productCollection->setPageSize($limit)->setCurPage($current_page);
    }
```

here the full code :

```
<?php
/**
* Product list template
*
* @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
*/
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php

$cat = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('cat');
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($cat == '')
    $currentCategoryId = $_category->getId();
else
    $currentCategoryId = $cat;

$limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();        

if($limit == ""){
    $limit = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
}

?>
<!-- No Product -->
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml();
    $current_page = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();        
?>

<?php
    if($currentCategoryId){
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortOrder();
        $direction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
        $display = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();

         if($order == 'name') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('name', $direction);
         }

         if($order == 'price') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('price', $direction);
         }

         if($order == 'position') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('position', $direction);
         }

         if($order == '') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')
                 ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
        }

        //layered navigation handling
        //price
        $price = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $class = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('class');
        $silos = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('silos');

        if($price != ''){
            $arr_price = explode('-',$price);

            if($arr_price[1] == '')
                $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=> $arr_price[0]));
            else
                $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=> $arr_price[0], 'to' => $arr_price[1]));
        }

        if($class != ''){
            $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('class', $class);
        }

        if($silos != ''){
            $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('silos', $silos);
        }
    }

    if($limit != 'all'){
        $_productCollection->setPageSize($limit)->setCurPage($current_page);
    }

?>
<!-- List mode -->
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
<?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <!-- Product Image -- >
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">                
            <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
        </a>
        <!-- Product description -->
        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="f-fix">
                <div class="product-primary">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="product-secondary">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="product-secondary">
                    <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                        <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="desc std">
                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

<?php else: ?>

<!-- Grid Mode -->

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php
    //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount
    $_columnCount = 4;
?>
<ul class="products-grid ali-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
    <?php $i=0;
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>            
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

            <div class="img-prod">
                <?php                    
                if($_product->getSpecialPrice()):
                ?>
                <div class="embel-embel sale"><?php echo $this->__('Sale')?><span class="sale"></span></div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php                    
                    $date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
                    $newtodate = $_product['news_to_date'];
                    $newfromdate = $_product['news_from_date'];

                    if (isset($newfromdate) and isset($newtodate) and $date >= $newfromdate and $date <= $newtodate) :
                ?>                                         
                <div class="embel-embel new"><?php echo $this->__('New')?><span class="new"></span></div>

                <?php
                    elseif(isset($newfromdate)):
                ?>
                <div class="embel-embel new"><?php echo $this->__('New')?><span class="new"></span></div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(238,317); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
                <div class="prod-title"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></div>
                <h2 style="display:none" class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php

                ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

                <div class="actions" style="display:none">
                    <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                        <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
    $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
```

or you can see it in here : http://pastebin.com/3bcAUSv2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> setCurPage() should be current page value

```
 if($currentCategoryId){
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortOrder();
        $direction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
        $display = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
        $limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
        // Default name for page number is p
```

> $currentPage = (int) ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ?
>   $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;

```
         if($order == 'name') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }                
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)                                          
                 ->setOrder('name', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($currentPage);

            //echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
            //$_productCollection->printLogQuery(true);
         }

         if($order == 'price') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('price', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($currentPage);
         }

         if($order == 'position') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('position', $direction)//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($currentPage);
         }

         if($order == '') {
            if($direction == '') {
                $direction = 'asc';
            }
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId)
                 ->getProductCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                 ->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')
                 ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')//;
                 ->setPageSize($limit)
                 ->setCurPage($currentPage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @minesh-patel, thank you for your quick response.I've tried but still was not successful. even if you choose _All_ choice, the products only show 1 product that appear.

Comment: check parameter name for page number is p ?

Comment: and where you have implemented this in toolbar block ?

Comment: Yes, parameter name for page number is p. http://sd.local.web/football/footwear.html?p=2. I implemented this in list.phtml, below `<? Php echo $ this-> getToolbarHtml ()?>` code.

Comment: Your way is completely wrong

Comment: use magento override / rewrite way and you can achieve this

Comment: the problem is you have called   <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?> which is based on product collection and you have override var   $_productCollection and assigned your custom collection in it

Comment: after trying several times I finally get the code (without override / rewrite). I will enter it in answers column.